# Can I Search for a Specific Row and Update it?? Google BigQuery Question

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery and was wondering if there was a way to search for a specific row, then individually update its columns using a Query. I am very new to database and SQL, and would love some of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Typically this is achieved through data manipulation language (DML).  For this specific example you would want use an `UPDATE` statement.
Documentation on this can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

As a word of caution verify your where clause before you execute to ensure you are targeting the correct rows.

For example:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET assigned_to_user = 'updated_value' -- the value you want to update to
WHERE -- this is where you define your criteria to narrow down to a subset of rows
 criteria_column = 'target_values' -- this is your critera
 -- and criteria_column_2 = 'other_value' -- if you need to expand more critiera just use logic operators like `and` or `or`
```

You can also test out what will be updated by issuing a select statement with the same criteria as your update and seeing which columns come back, for example:

```
select *
from your_table
WHERE 
 criteria_column = 'target_values'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Daniel.
So when attempting to target specific rows, is there a way to find out exactly where a specific row is? For example, if I'd like to find a name of someone specific, would there be a way to identify which row that name is in? Thank you again!

Comment: if you can update your question with an example record you would like to find and the updated output I can help you out a little more

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I have a table on BigQuery with devices in our environment from a CSV I created. I am trying to update a column titled "Assigned_to_user" for each serial number. But currently, I am trying to see what it would look like if I had to manually use a query to find a row by keyword, then follow it up by updating that column for that row.

Comment: I added a mocked example